# Passport local strategy through custom fetch not displaying flash messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, promise, passport-local

I am using passport local strategy to enable user login.
Earlier, my backend code was -

```
passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect : '/dashboard',
      failureRedirect : '/users/login',
      failureFlash : true
    })(req, res, next)
```

Later, I implemented a google recaptcha (which required a custom callback function using jquery/JS). This is as follows -

```
document.getElementById("login-form").addEventListener('submit', submitForm)
  function submitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    const email = $("#email").val()
    const password = $("#password").val()
    const captcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val()

    fetch('/users/login', {
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({email:email,password:password, captcha:captcha})
    })
    .then(response=>{
      console.log(response)
      if (response.redirected) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
        else{
          
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.info(err + " url: " + url);
    });
```

Now, before implementing the custom callback, passport automatically displayed **Missing Credentials** flash message incase fields were empty, however, now that I am using custom callback, the following data is logged. I am not sure how to display the **flash messages**. Please ignore the inconsistency of the code in the sense that it contains js and jquery and function() and ()=>{}, etc.

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/users/login", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/users/login"
__proto__: Response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a robust solution to this, but I have implemented this on the frontend -

Basically, if the captcha is filled, the local strategy redirects the user to either /login or /dashboard (depending upon whether the details are valid or not)
If the captcha **isn't** filled, the server sends a json object in response.

Now, my frontend checks if it a **redirect object** or the other json object.

If it is the json one, it means the captcha was missing and hence an error flash message is displayed.

If it is the redirect URL, then it redirects if it is /dashboard, otherwise adds an error flash message if it is /login.

```
<script>

   var onloadCallback = function() {
        widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('captcha-preview'), {
         'sitekey' : 'insert_key_here'
       });
    };

  document.getElementById("login-form").addEventListener('submit', submitForm)
  
  function submitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    const email = $("#email").val()
    const password = $("#password").val()
    const captcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val()

    fetch('/users/login', {
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({email:email,password:password, captcha:captcha})
    })
    .then(response=>{

      // Incase captcha is verified, the response redirects the user
      if (response.redirected) {

        // If the redirect is to the users/login, captcha is reloaded
            if(response.url.includes(window.location.pathname)){
              grecaptcha.reset(widgetId2)
              $("#display-error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">Invalid Login Credentials<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button></div>')
            }else{

              // If the redirect is /dashboard, the redirect is made
              window.location.href = response.url;
            }
        }
        else if(!response.redirected){
          $("#display-error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">Missing captcha<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button></div>')
        }
    })

  }
</script>
```