# How to be redirected by Express backend after successfully submitted the requiest from the frontend by Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

Below code fragment represents the usual signing in logic for the backend.
If credenctials are correct, the user will be redirected to the admin panel:

```js
import Express from "express";
import { Controller, Post, Body as RequestBody, Res as HTTP_Response } from "routing-controllers";


@Controller()
class AccessControlController {

    @Post("/api/sign_in")
    protected async signIn(
        @Res() response: Express.Response
    ): Promise<Express.Response> {
    
        // check the user name and password
        // if password is correct update the session
    
        response.redirect("/admin");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Writing this code I have expected that if response has been returned to the frontend, the user will be automatically redirected to the `/admin` destination.

```js
async function signIn() {

    try {

        await fetch("/api/sign_in", { method: "post", body: JSON.stringify({ /* ... */ }) })

    } catch {

    // ...
        
        return;
        
    }

    // ↓ If I need to write this on the frontend, no need in `response.redirect("/admin");` at backend?
    // window.location.href = "/admin"

    console.log("End");

}
```

I has been surprised when the script have reached the `console.log("End");` line without redirection. If to output the response of the `fetch` it will include:

```js
{
  ok: true,
  redirected: true,
  status: 200, // not 302!
  // ...
}
```

Of course the redirect will work if I comment out the `window.location.href = "/admin"` line. But should not just `response.redirect("/admin");` at backend be enough?

Comment: so, you are redirecting a fetch - that doesn't change the current page you're in

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for the comment. I am sorry, I have not understood what exactly you want to say. Do you mean "The redirection on server side does not make the fetch API to make redirect on the client side; the redirection on server side works only when posting the data via HTML form without AJAX"? Even if so, it is still unclear why the `response` object of Fetch API has the [`redirect` property](https://javascript.info/fetch-api#redirect).

Comment: It is what I said, can't explain it any better, perhaps someone else can explain it better to you

Comment: Don't respond to async requests with redirects. It's basically pointless. I suggest you read this post ~ [What is the difference between post API call and form submission with post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58230870/283366)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fetch` function can follow the redirection, but it will not change the URL on the page. You have to manually redirect, you can use the URL from the server to redirect either to `admin` or to `login` page.

```js
function signIn(email, password) {
  const opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({email, password}),
    redirect: 'follow', //  set follow value
  }

  return fetch('/api/sign_in', opts)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.redirected) {
        window.location.href = res.url //  you can place logic on server side where to redirect
        return Promise.reject('Redirecting')
      }
      return res
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(() => console.log('End'))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the comments and the post "[What is the difference between post API call and form submission with post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58230870/6309)", [AJAX requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (including Fetch API) and traditional form submissions handle redirects differently.

- Traditional form submissions will automatically update the browser's display and follow redirects.
- AJAX requests, such as those made with Fetch API, do not automatically change the browser's display upon redirects; they only fetch the redirected content.

In an Express.js application with a structure like this:

```bash
 Project Root Directory
 |
 ├── node_modules/ [Dependencies]
 |
 ├── public/ [Static Files]
 |    ├── css/ [CSS Files]
 |    ├── images/ [Image Files]
 |    └── js/ [JavaScript Files]
 |         └── formSubmitter.js
 |         └── login.js  [Contains the AJAX request and window.location code]
 |
 ├── views/ [View Templates]
 |    ├── index.ejs
 |    └── ...
 |
 ├── app.js [Express Application Entry Point]
 |
 └── package.json [Project Metadata and Dependencies]
```

---

#### AJAX/Fetch API approach

For AJAX or Fetch API, you need to handle redirections manually in your JavaScript. Although Fetch API can automatically follow redirects, it does not update the browser's display or URL. Your JavaScript should process the final response and update `window.location` if necessary.

The `/js/formSubmitter.js` script for this approach includes a check for redirection and handles it manually (a bit as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792450/6309)):

```js
// Function to submit data using Fetch API and handle redirects
function submitForm(url, data) {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // Serialize data
        redirect: 'manual' // Do not automatically follow redirects
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 302 || response.status === 301) { // Check for redirect status
            const redirectUrl = response.headers.get('Location');
            window.location.href = redirectUrl; // Manually update the window location to the redirect URL
        } else {
            return response.json(); // Process the response data if no redirect
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            console.log(data); // Log or process the data
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

That script would work for single-page applications (SPAs), or scenarios requiring control over the submission process without a full-page reload.

---

#### Traditional Form submission approach

If you need to make a POST request followed by a server-side redirect (e.g., in payment gateways), dynamically creating and submitting a form is a better approach. That method simulates a traditional form submission, allowing the browser to handle the POST request and automatically follow server-side redirects.

The `formSubmitter.js` script for traditional form submission:

```js
function submitForm(url, data) {
    const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = 'post';
    form.action = url;

    // Add hidden fields to the form
    for (const key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
            hiddenField.name = key;
            hiddenField.value = data[key];
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit(); // Browser will follow the server-side redirect
}
```

In your `app.js`, make sure to serve static files, allowing client-side scripts to be accessed:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public')); // Serve static files

// Other Express configurations

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running on port 3000'));
```

In your `index.ejs` or other HTML templates, include the `formSubmitter.js` script and use it for form submissions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Web Page</title>
    <!-- Other head elements -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Web Page</h1>

    <form id="myForm">
        <!-- Form fields -->
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/js/formSubmitter.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = {/* Form data collection */};
            submitForm('/api/submit', formData);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the form is submitted, `submitForm` dynamically creates and submits a form. The browser will then automatically follow any server-side redirection.

Comment: Won't using `follow` then manually navigating result in a duplicate request? Seems like a bad idea to me

Comment: @Phil I agree. I have removed the `redirect: 'follow'` option is used in the Fetch request.